# Is there any performance hit with lots of empty tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Are there any performance issues with having lots of empty tables in MySQL? My CMS system has loads of optional features, and the build script adds all the necessary tables to the database in case they're needed in the future. Can anyone think of if and why this might be detrimental to performance? Disk space not really an issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of any: In mySQL, a table consists of a number of files in the local file system.

Files laying dormant shouldn't be a problem. (Well, except if you have thousands or tens of thousands of tables: That might cause trouble not so much for the database, but for the file system. But I doubt that is the case here.)

Comment: Cheers - thought was the case, but nice to get confirmation!

Comment: @Ali myISAM definitely stores 3 or 4 files per table; I don't know how InnoDB does it. The [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines) doesn't provide the information

Answer (score 3):

if you really hit big numbers of tables you'll maybe have to tune your config parameters on file descriptors and table caches. See for example this discussion:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?93,120120,120703#msg-120703

Comment: Nice one, cheers. I think this is only for queries involving large numbers of tables, so shouldn't affect my app, but a very useful and informative article.

Comment: If several different requests impact several tables, and you cache table is too short, you'll be impacted, but that's not a very heavy cache miss.

Comment: regilero: +1, didn't know about that - so if there are many tables, and if they are queried at any moment, this will cause the `table_cache` to be "overfilled", right? This is indeed relevant (and if I were the OP this would be my accepted answer).